# would the pointer returned by new(size, value) Type[0] be legal and could it be used to build an array?

Tags: c++, c++11, standards-compliance, array-initialization

The standard says, in `5.3.4[expr.new]/7`

> When the value of the expression in a direct-new-declarator is zero, the allocation function is called to allocate an array with no elements.

and in `3.7.3.1[basic.stc.dynamic.allocation]/2`

> The effect of dereferencing a pointer returned as a request for zero size is undefined.

But if the allocation function is user-defined and it knows it returned a valid pointer, would it still be undefined behavior to dereference it? Can the standard mandate undefined behavior of user code?

The reason I ask is yet another meaningless attempt to initialize a dynamic array of objects of non-default-constructible type. What problems does it have, besides the obvious lack of `delete[]` and that it can only be called with `[0]`? Did I even use `aligned_storage` correctly?

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

struct T {
   int val;
   T() = delete;
   T(int i) : val(i) {}
   void* operator new[](std::size_t, std::size_t cnt, const T& t)
   {
       typedef std::aligned_storage<sizeof(t),
                    std::alignment_of<T>::value>::type buf;
       T* ptr = reinterpret_cast<T*>(new buf[cnt]);
       std::uninitialized_fill_n(ptr, cnt, t);
       return ptr;
    }
};

int main()
{
    T* a = new(100, T(7)) T[0]; // using zero is legal per 5.3.4/7

    std::cout << "a[0] = " << a[0].val << '\n' // but is this legal?
              << "a[1] = " << a[1].val << '\n'
              << "a[98] = " << a[98].val << '\n'
              << "a[99] = " << a[99].val << '\n';
    delete[] a; // free the 100 aligned_storages
}
```

test run: http://ideone.com/iBW0z

also compiles and runs as expected with  with MSVC++ 2010 EE

Comment: "*The reason I ask is yet another meaningless attempt to initialize a dynamic array of objects of non-default-constructible type.*" Why isn't `std::vector` sufficient? It allows exactly this.

Comment: @ildjarn: it is more than sufficient for that purpose, yes. I am just exploring the boundaries of the language.

Comment: I'm also not sure about the offset the `new` operator returns. I think, for all that `new` knows, it could call your `operator new` with the unnamed `size_t` parameter equal to `100 * sizeof(T)`, and offset the resulting buffer by `100 * sizeof(T)`. Or more realistically, call it with `sizeof(size_t)` and offset by `sizeof(size_t)` to store the count of elements of the array (needed to know how many dtors to call later), instead of calling it with size of `0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an irritating logic problem in your code:

The new expression:

```
T* a = new(100, T(7)) T[0];
```

Calls T's deleted default constructor [expr.new]/17. ;-(

`std::vector<T>` is sure looking good about now... :-)

Comment: I see, it wants the constructor to be accessible. Every time I try to outsmart C++, it outsmarts me.

Comment: So you could call operator new directly, instead of using a new expression.  This is essentially what vector does.  But since vector already does it, I'm not sure what the motivating use case is.  vector doesn't require default constructible unless you request it.

Comment: the motivation was an attempt to justify a `new(...) T[0]`, and the motivation for that was curiosity.

Comment: Curiosity is an excellent motivator! :-)  Try moving your operator new to global scope and calling it directly, instead of via a new expression:  T* a = static_cast<T*>(operator new[](sizeof(T)*0, 100, T(7)));

Answer (score 1):

The only non-undefined behavior of the use of the result of a `reinterpret_cast` is when the cast is back to its original type, so you already have UB there even if everything else was ok.

If you really need this, why don't you just make a function that allocates a large enough block of contiguous memory and then placement `new`s a bunch of `T` into that memory?

Comment: although all I'm doing is incrementing the pointer and casting it to void, I guess it would be better defined to have called `get_temporary_buffer`, which returns `T*`, instead of newing an array of `aligned_storage`s? Making it a separate function means I'm just implementing vector, that's been done.